# Submit button won't send email or start an action on the server

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit

I have been working on this contact form for ages now and still haven't been able to send a working e-mail.  So instead of wasting my time just guess and checking different solutions I figured I might ask for some help.

The form looks like this:

```html
<form action="assets/php/contact.php" name="contact" id="contact" role="form" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name*" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your E-mail*" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="category">Video Category</label>
    <input type="text" id="category" class="form-control" name="category" placeholder="Category*" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter the catergory.">
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="7" placeholder="Message*" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message."></textarea>
    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-round btn-dark">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Any my contact.php file looks like so:

```
<?php
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        $from = 'Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'testemail@gmail.com'; 
        $body = "From: $name\n Category: $category\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Currently whenever I press the submit button on my site, the page does nothing.  Before I was getting a 404 error for my PHP file but I seem to have fixed that.

Comment: you dont have a value for `$_POST['submit'] so this will fail `if($_POST['submit'])` assign a value to the button or remove the if statement

Comment: Is this the correct format without the if statement? 

`$_POST['submit'] {
        if (mail ($to, $subject,...`

Comment: no its not. thats very basic php which you should know

Comment: Sorry I've only used php a few times, I just need an email form and most tutorials were using this method.  `isset($_POST["submit"]) returns true` is a better version right?  I just have to add the `value="submit"` to my input.

Comment: replace `returns true` with `&& !empty($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: google if statements w3 schools will have a simple version of it. There is really no need to check if there is a post submit, if there is post data there something was submitted. Since you have not used php before, I would recommend you get a dev involved, the code above is completely lacking in security measures. If you want to learn, you'll need to study a bit. But don't try and shortcut it, you will overlook something important!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-round btn-dark">Submit</button>
```

Probably should be this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-round btn-dark">
```

Comment: I tried the solution but it still didn't run the script and send the email.

Answer (score 0):

`<form>` tag doesn't need a name attribute plus
you should replace

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-round btn-dark">Submit</button>
```

with this

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-round btn-dark">
```

your php code will throw undefined index error because there is no such $_POST['name'] or $_POST['email'] yet but it won't stop the execution 
you should modify it into this

```
 <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $category = $_POST['category'];
            $from = 'Contact Form'; 
            $to = 'testemail@gmail.com'; 
            $body = "From: $name\n Category: $category\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Ok I tried this solution but it still isn't sending the email.

Comment: ok after you hit the submit button what do you get? if a blank blank page is what you get try to echo something inside the if statement to check whether the form is submitted or not

Comment: I get no response visually as the site doesn't change, but in chrome inspection view, the form does flash so I know that the button is working.

Comment: you forgot to echo the $result !

Comment: ok i tested your code through a php file all works i assume that your question here that why is the email is not being sent right? did u configure all of your settings so you can send an email? is it your first email?

Comment: How would I need to configure the settings?  Would it be through the cPanel of my site?

Comment: Are you sending the email via localhost?